# How to animate a Positioned widget from top to bottom in a Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The following code does not work since I believe `Tween`s do not work with `null` values:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedStackDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AnimatedStackDemoState createState() => AnimatedStackDemoState();
}

class AnimatedStackDemoState extends State<AnimatedStackDemo> {
  bool _isAnimated = false;

  void _toggleAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _isAnimated = !_isAnimated;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Animated Stack Demo'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _toggleAnimation,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            top: _isAnimated ? null : -200.0,
            bottom: _isAnimated ? -200.0 : null,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: AnimatedStackDemo(),
  ));
}
```

How can I accomplish this? I want to take advantage of the stack Widget so I don't want to use max constraints/screen size, only relative values of the stack (top, bottom, left, right, height and width).

**Edit:** I should have made explicit that I want to start `top: -widgetSize` and end at `bottom: -widgetSize`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AnimatedAlign` widget.

```dart
AnimatedAlign(
  alignment: _isAnimated ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.bottomLeft,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  child: Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
),
```

Comment: I have updated my example. AnimatedAlign would not work for my use case I think.

Comment: I am not so sure about your thought why it won't work. btw on your current example container doesnt show up

Comment: Because I want to animate it from outside the screen (top) to out of the screen (bottom).

Comment: means working with negative value from current view? Can  you include full snippet what exactly you are facing

Comment: Yes exactly (negative values). If you check the example its already there:
`top: _isAnimated ? null : -200.0,` and `bottom: _isAnimated ? -200.0 : null`.

Comment: But you cant not provide the `height` & `top,bottm` at the same time. You can also use negative value on alignment  like `Alignment(0, -2.0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the desired behaviour by only using one param (top, or bottom) and then using the height of the Stack inside of your calculations as well. This can be done by wrapping the Stack inside of a LayoutBuilder, so that they size of the Stack is used and not the max Screen size.

So you start at for example top -**childHeight** and animate to **stackHeight** + **height**.

Here is your modified example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedStackDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AnimatedStackDemoState createState() => AnimatedStackDemoState();
}

class AnimatedStackDemoState extends State<AnimatedStackDemo> {
  bool _isAnimated = false;

  void _toggleAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _isAnimated = !_isAnimated;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Animated Stack Demo'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _toggleAnimation,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.green),
              buildAnimatedChild(200, 200, constraints.maxHeight),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildAnimatedChild(double width, double height, double maxHeight) {
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      top: _isAnimated ? maxHeight + height : -height,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: width,
        height: height,
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: AnimatedStackDemo(),
  ));
}
```